# How do I make jQuerymobile show page loading animation until I get a JSON response from the server?

Tags: cordova, jquery-mobile, mustache

I am using PhoneGap + jQueryMobile + Mustache JS to create an app for mobile devices.

To make sure the app is responsive and works minimally in offline mode too, I am packaging the Html, images, CSS and JS files in the app. However, the app needs to interact with remote server and based on its JSON response dynamically render the web-page.

Actually the html assets have Mustache markup and the remote JSON response is fed into Mustache JS to replace the markups.

So, what I thought was to listen for `pagebeforeload` and use `event.preventDefault()` to do stop jQM from carrying out the task itself. Below is the code:-

```
function pageLoader(event, pdata) {

    if ($(window).data(pdata.dataUrl + '-suppress')) {  // <---- UGLY HACK to prevent this from getting called the 2nd time.
        $(window).removeData(pdata.dataUrl + '-suppress');
        return;
    }

    event.preventDefault();

    $.getJSON(
            'http://myserver/json',
            {
                src : pdata.dataUrl
            },
            function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {

                if (data.success) {
                    $(window).data(pdata.dataUrl + '-suppress', true);

                    $.mobile.loadPage(pdata.absUrl, pdata.options).done(
                            function(url, options, newPage, dupCachedPage) {
                                newPage.html(Mustache.render(
                                        newPage.html(), data.view));

                                pdata.deferred.resolve(url, options,
                                        newPage, dupCachedPage);
                            }).fail(function(url, options) {
                        pdata.deferred.reject(url, options);
                    });

                } else {
                    pdata.deferred.reject(pdata.dataUrl, pdata.options);
                }

            }).fail(function() {
        pdata.deferred.reject(pdata.dataUrl, pdata.options);
    });
}
```

## What the above code does

The above code prevents the default page load action. It then makes a JSON request. When the response comes it then uses `$.mobile.loadPage` to load the actual html page. After that it passes the JSON response + the html to Mustache to get the final html, which is again inserted into the DOM. Finally it calls the deferred object to let jQM know that we are done loading the page.

## Problems in the above approach I would like to fix

1. When the index page renders, this method is not invoked so the page is rendered without Mustache. I don't see any way to make jQM keep showing the loading message until I am done loading the JSON and re-rendering the html.
2. I am using an ugly hack to keep my event listener from getting invoked again by `loadPage`, when I invoke that manually. I am using `loadPage` instead of `$.ajax()` since that method provides more features like parsing out only the part of the page in `data-role="page"` part and executing the script within that only. It would had been nice if that method was exposed as helper function.